# How to resolved namespace conflicts?

Tags: c#

I am using one base dll named as KSWeb.dll. It has main namespace is KSWeb.This dll has main Base class Under KSWeb.KSS.Base.

Now I have added this as reference in of one of the class library project. I want to give namespace to this class library also KSWeb.I have added a new class named as NewCK which inherits from KSWeb.KSS.Base.

When I am doing coding means KSWEB and then process dot(.) then it can found KSS and then found Base also.

My problem is when I build this class library then it gives me error like KSWEB.KSS not found and then I press alter + tab KSWEB.KSS not found.

Why is it so? please refere below code.

Now in this class library project I have create a class like

```
namespace KSWeb
{
    partial class NewCK : KSWeb.KSS.Base
    {
    }
}
```

for my point of view it is compulsory to use KSWEB namespace in class library
Please suggest in c#.net or in vb.net.

Comment: `global::KSWeb.KSS.Base`

Comment: It's really unclear what asemblies and namespaces there are, what their relations are and what problems you have. Furthermore, Visual Studio is pretty good at suggesting autocompletion for code that won't compile. Make sure you don't have any warnings or errors left apart from the one you're focusing on.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't happening because your base dll is not available for your project? For example, your dll might be compiled for Framework 4.51 and your project is set to compile for Framework 4.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Use a namespace alias

   using Other = KSWeb.KSS;

    namespace KSWeb
    {
        partial class NewCK : Base
        {
          //You can now use Other as below
           Other.Method();
        }
    }
```